# How to extend XCTest to create custom test framework

Tags: swift, xctest

I'm experimenting with creating a `XCTest` class using the following code:

```
class NarfTest:XCTest {

    override var testCaseCount: Int {
        return 2
    }

    override var name: String {
        return "abcdef"
    }

    override var testRunClass: AnyClass? {
        return XCTestRun.self
    }


    override func perform(_ run:XCTestRun) {
        run.start()
        run.recordFailure(withDescription: "abc", inFile: "def", atLine: 1, expected: true)
        run.stop()
    }
}

class NarfTestRunner: XCTestCase {

    override class var defaultTestSuite:XCTestSuite {
        let suite = XCTestSuite(name: "hello suite")
        suite.addTest(NarfTest())
        return suite
    }
}
```

When I run this I get this log:

```
Test Suite 'Selected tests' started at 2017-11-11 00:30:17.081
Test Suite 'NarfTests.xctest' started at 2017-11-11 00:30:17.082
Test Suite 'hello suite' started at 2017-11-11 00:30:17.083
2017-11-11 00:30:17.082894+1100 xctest[11264:894722] *** Assertion failure in -[NarfTests.NarfTest testRun], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest/XCTest-13763/Sources/XCTestFramework/Core/XCAbstractTest.m:98
<unknown>:0: error: hello suite : Invalid test run class: XCTestRun. Must be a subclass of: (null)
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3230613b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff58ed3c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff3230bed2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff34417260 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
    4   XCTest                              0x00000001003979ad -[XCTest testRun] + 327
    5   XCTest                              0x00000001003979d7 -[XCTest runTest] + 27
    6   XCTest                              0x000000010035ffa6 __27-[XCTestSuite performTest:]_block_invoke + 363
    7   XCTest                              0x000000010035f90d -[XCTestSuite _performProtectedSectionForTest:testSection:] + 26
    8   XCTest                              0x000000010035fb0a -[XCTestSuite performTest:] + 239
....
```

I've been trying to work out why this code isn't working and studying the code at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-xctest but the code there appears to be different to the XCTest being run by Xcode.

For example, the GitHub version run auto instantiate the class returned from `var testRunClass:AnyClass?` where as the Xcode version throws the error above.

Then there are the method names. The GitHub project has a method called `run()` where as the trace above shows a method called `runTest()`.

Has anyone tried creating a custom extension of the 'XCTest' class? How did you get it to work?

P.S. and before anyone asks, I'm not extending `XCTestCase` because I'm playing around with the idea of creating a test from something other than a method :-)

Comment: Hey, I'm doing this exact same thing right now, did you ever solve it?

Comment: Hello hello, trying to do something similar. Any further reading somewhere?

Comment: Sorry. Haven't looked at this for a while and probably won't.